# Airflow Branch Operator and S3KeySensor doesnot respect trigger_rule='none_failed'

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

I have 3 S3KeySensors on different files in different folders. 2 of them have to be successful and the third one can be skipped.I am trying to trigger the downstream task with the trigger_rule='none_failed' but S3KeySensor doesnot seem to respect that. This is how my DAG looks like.

[This is how it behaves](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pptdn.png)

[This is how i want it to behave:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCjPM.png)

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `trigger_rule="none_failed_or_skipped"` to `test_step` task as explained in this [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html#trigger-rules).

From the documentation:
`none_failed_or_skipped`: all parents have not failed (failed or upstream_failed) and at least one parent has succeeded.

Comment: "none_failed_or_skipped" thats available in airflow version 1.10.12 and I am on 1.10.9 upgrading to the new version is not in my control. I was wondering if there is a workaround to get the results that i want. Thanks